# redisplay PHP form with errors

Tags: php

I have a dozen fully functional scripts that use heredoc statements to display HTML including e.g. `$errors[field_name]` yet this nearly identical script results in **POST** errors like

> "Notice: Undefined index: user_password in register.php on line 162"

When the user enters a password with 5 characters when 8+ characters are required, a validation function populates `$errors['password']` and the form is supposed to re-display along with validation errors.

Can't see what I'm missing in this Bootstrap style form. The `$errors` array is global and I can force the display of errors, so I know errors are initialized but I keep getting

> "Notice: Undefined index"

```
$fields = array( 'user_name', 'user_email', 'user_password', 'user_password2' );

function display_form($string = '')
{
    global $error_token, $cfg, $fields, $form, $errors, $s, $token, $validation_status;
    $error_message = '';
    switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
        Case 'POST':
            // validation failed, redisplay the form
            $autofocus = '';
            foreach($fields as $field){
                $$field = htmlentities(get_cgi_var($field), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                // wrap errors in Bootstrap alert markup
                $errors[$field] = !empty($errors[$field]) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.htmlentities($errors[$field], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</div>' : '';
                // debug, force the premature display of errors.
                // echo !empty($errors[$field]) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.htmlentities($errors[$field], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</div>' : '<p>empty</p>';
            }
            break;
        Case 'GET':
        default:
            $autofocus = 'autofocus';
            foreach($fields as $field){
                $$field = '';
                $errors[$field] = '';
            }
            $error_token = '';
            break;
    };
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $validation_status[$field] = empty($errors[$field]) ? ' has-success' : ' has-error';
    }
    $self = SELF;

print<<<_HTML_
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Registration</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      $string
      $error_message
      <form name="form1" id="form1" action="$self" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
      $error_token
      $errors[user_name]
      <div class="row form-group$validation_status[user_name]">
        <label for="user_name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="$user_name" maxlength="255" $autofocus required placeholder="Your First &amp; Last Name" title="Your First &amp; Last Name" autocomplete="on" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      $errors[user_email]
      <div class="row form-group$validation_status[user_email]">
        <label for="user_email" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="$user_email" maxlength="255" required placeholder="Your Email Address" autocomplete="on" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      $errors[user_password]
      <div class="row form-group$validation_status[user_password]">
        <label for="user_password" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input type="text" name="user_password" id="user_password" value="$user_password" maxlength="255" required placeholder="Password or Passphrase" autocomplete="on" class="form-control">
          <p class="help-block">Case sensitive password containing 8+ characters or a phrase containing 3-5 words</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      $errors[user_password2]
      <div class="row form-group$validation_status[user_password2]">
        <label for="user_password2" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input type="text" name="user_password2" id="user_password2" value="$user_password2" maxlength="255" required placeholder="Re-enter Password or Passphrase" autocomplete="on" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="submit_button" class="col-lg-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 text-center">
          <input type="hidden" name="token" value="$token">
          <input type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" value="Submit" onClick="return captcha_validation(this.form);" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
      </div><!-- /panel-body -->
      <div class="panel-footer text-center">&nbsp;</div>
  </div><!-- /panel -->
</div><!-- /col -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="well">unused column</div>
</div><!-- /col -->
_HTML_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
default:
    $autofocus = 'autofocus';
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $$field = ''; // <------------------
        $errors[$field] = '';
    }
    $error_token = '';
    break;
```

replace `$$field` with `$field` or remove it altogether - it's not needed here.

Comment: Would that generate an undefined index error? I thought that those were only generated when you were accessing an array, though I'll admit that I've never used a variable variable...

Comment: `$errors` is an array and your foreach in the `default` switch case is iterating through the `$fields` and setting the `$field` as the key on the `$errors` array and empty string as the value. Later in your code that builds the `_HTML_` - you are attempting to use the key like this `$errors[user_password]` however, this will not work, because your typo is not generating any keys. so yes, short answer, your typo can lead to undefined index...

Comment: try my answer/suggestion do let us know if it works or not. If it doesn't - i suspect the fault is elsewhere...

Comment: `$$field` isn't a typo; the OP is creating a variable variable. In this case, he's initialising variables called `$user_name`, `$user_email`, and so on. He's also initialzing the `$errors` array with those same values.

Comment: I think there were 2 problems. One being Chrome browser keeps serving up results from prior 'test" submissions, thus displaying un-real results. The main issue appeared to correct itself after switching from `!empty()` to `isset()` to evaluate `$errors[$field]`. Having put the computer to sleep for a couple hours, the form appears to work as planned using evaluation with either method. I hate computers. Gremlins, cache issues, no telling now what was the exact problem.